# How can I disable SSH password authentication on 15.04

Tags: ssh, 15.04

I have added the following line to /etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

And restarted my sshd with

```
sudo service sshd restart
sudo service ssh restart
```

No output from either, dont know if it restarted or not. Tryed restarting with this too:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

But still when I connect via SSH it prompts for credentials and lets me log in. I'm not doing anything differently from the 4 versions of Ubuntu previously which I have done this for - any ideas why Ubuntu 15.04 no longer respects the "PasswordAuthentication no" line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two near identical config files:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

and

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

For the SSH server, put the setting in the sshd config file, NOT the ssh config file.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install openssh-server

cd /etc/ssh/
vi sshd.config

#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

uncomment it and change it to NO

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

then restart the ssh service

```
service ssh restart

root@stack:/etc/ssh# service ssh restart
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 4118
```